# How to send application via SMS packets

Tags: installation, gsm

Is this possible to send an application using SMS packets?

Anyway, is it possible send an application on GSM?

Thanks.

Comment: No answer!!?  What's the problem in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. You should distribute your app through the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to send an application over SMS. However each SMS is only 140B.

It's also possible to send applications through the mail on sheets of A4 paper, it's just usually not advised.

Comment: How can I send an application over SMS? 
Could you please tell me some resources, or keyword to search?

Comment: The question is so broad that I can't help any further than telling you it's possible.

Comment: Thanks. But if I know some keywords or a general resource, I can find it. I don't know any resource or keyword to search, even after many searches. A little guidance will help me a lot.